# SocketIO - Backend emit() event doesn't reach React client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have been trying for a long time to implement a chat in React and Express using SocketIO and I am very close to finish, but unfortunately I've hit a dead end because a function that should work doesn't.

I can't seem to be able to link `emit()` from inside a `join()` to a `socket.on` on the client (React).

I have been following some guides, but their code just works when mine does not.

Why can't I get anything in the client when `emit()` is inside a `join()` ?

```js
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import config from './config.js';

import authRoutes from './routes/authRoutes.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import roomRoutes from './routes/roomRoutes.js';
import chatRoutes from './routes/chatRoutes.js';

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:3001'],
  },
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/rooms', roomRoutes);
app.use('/api/chat', chatRoutes);

const users = [];

const userJoin = (id, room, socketId, name) => {
  const user = { id, room, socketId, name };
  !users.some(
    (user) => user.id === id && user.room === room && user.name === name
  ) && users.push(user);
  return user;
};

const getCurrentUser = (socketId) => {
  return users.find((user) => user.socketId === socketId);
};

const userLeave = (socketId) => {
  const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.socketId === socketId);
  if (index !== -1) {
    return users.splice(index, 1)[0];
  }
};

const getRoomUsers = (room) => {
  return users.filter((user) => user.room === room);
};

const messageFormat = (messageText, sentBy) => {
  const message = { messageText, sentBy, timestamp: new Date().toUTCString() };
  return message;
};

const botName = 'BOT';

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  //  Connecting
  console.log('A user has connected.');
  // Join room
  socket.on('joinRoom', ({ id, chatID, name }) => {
    const user = userJoin(id, chatID, socket.id, name);
    socket.join(user.room, () => {
      // socket.emit('getMessage', messageFormat('Welcome to Landmarks', botName));
      // socket.broadcast
      //   .to(user.room)
      //   .emit('sendMessage', messageFormat(`${user.name} has joined the chat.`, botName));
      // Send user and room info

      io.to(user.room).emit('getUserRooms', {
        room: user.room,
        users: getRoomUsers(user.room),
      });
      // socket.on('sendUserRooms', () => {
      //   const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);
      //   console.log(user);
      // });
    });
  });

  // Send message
  socket.on('sendMessage', ({ sentBy, messageText }) => {
    const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);

    io.to(user.room).emit('getMessage', messageFormat(messageText, user.id));
  });

  // Disconnecting
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const user = userLeave(socket.id);

    if (user) {
      io.to(user.room).emit(
        'sendMessage',
        messageFormat(`${user.name} left the chat.`, user.id)
      );
      io.to(user.room).emit('getUserRooms', {
        room: user.room,
        users: getRoomUsers(user.room),
      });
    }

    console.log('User has disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`App is listening on url http://localhost:${config.port}`);
});
```

This is how my app is structured:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/'
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <Home />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        >
          <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
          <Route path='rooms' element={<LandingPage />}>
            <Route path='new' element={<CreateRoom />} />
            <Route path=':roomID' element={<RoomItem />} />
            <Route path=':roomID/edit' element={<EditRoom />} />
            <Route path='join/:inviteToken/' element={<JoinRoom />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='profile/:id' element={<Profile />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path='set-avatar' element={<SetAvatar />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Inside Room Item is Drawer and inside Drawer are both Chat and Members.

```js
// inside Room Item this is the only socketIO call
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentRoom) {
      dispatch(getMessages(currentRoom.chatID));
      dispatch(roomActions.setCurrentChat(currentRoom.chatID));
      dispatch(chatActions.reset());
    }
  }, [currentRoom, dispatch, currentUserID]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentChat) {
      socket.emit('joinRoom', {
        id: currentUserID,
        chatID: currentChat,
        name: name,
      });
    }
    console.log('do i get here');
  }, [currentChat, currentUserID, name]);
```

I am importing socket using  `import socket from '../SocketIO/socket';`
with

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('ws://localhost:8080');
export default socket;
```

And here is the Members component. Here I am only trying to get which users are in which rooms:

```js
import { List } from 'antd';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import socket from '../../SocketIO/socket';
import { roomActions } from '../roomSlice';
import classes from './Members.module.css';

export default function Members({ members, ownerID, currentUserID, chatID }) {
  const { onlineUsers } = useSelector((state) => state.room);
  const [online, setOnline] = useState([]);
  const [offline, setOffline] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  socket.on('getUserRooms', ({ room: roomID, users }) => {
    dispatch(roomActions.setOnlineUsers({ room: roomID, users }));
    console.log('here');
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(onlineUsers);
    setOnline(
      members.filter((el) => {
        return onlineUsers.some((foo) => foo.id === el.id);
      })
    );
    setOffline(
      members.filter((el) => {
        return onlineUsers.every((foo) => foo.id !== el.id);
      })
    );
  }, [onlineUsers, members, chatID]);

  // console.log('online', online);
  // console.log('offline', offline);

return (<></>);
```

I have tried moving `socket.on('getUserRooms')` everywhere, but it just doesn't gets fired up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your socket available everywhere I guess. You can achieve this by creating a separate file and defining a react context using createContext.

```js
//websocket.js

import React, {createContext } from 'react'
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3000/"

const WebSocketContext = createContext(null)

export { WebSocketContext }

export default ({ children }) => {
    let socket;
    let ws;

    if (!socket) {
        socket = openSocket(ENDPOINT, {transports:["websocket"]})

     
        socket.on("eventname", data=>{
             console.log(data)
           
          })
        
         
        ws = {
            socket: socket,
        }
    }

    return (
        <WebSocketContext.Provider value={ws}>
            {children}
        </WebSocketContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Then, you wrap the context around your routes so you can use socket inside the components.

```js
import WebSocketProvider from "path/to/websocket.js"

function App(){
  <WebSocketProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      //...
    </BrowserRouter>
  </WebSocketProvider>
}
```

you can then use the socket inside any of the components by importing the WebSocketContext

```js
import {WebSocketContext} from "path/to/websocket.js"
import {useContext} from "react"
function AnyOtherComponents(){
  let {socket} = useContext(WebSocketContext)
  useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on("event", data=>{
    //...
    })
  })
  
  return <></>
}
```

Comment: I've moved socket to Context just like in your answer but I get the same behavior: nothing inside `socket.join()` emits or if they emit I still can't receive anything on the front-end that possibly comes from emits inside `socket.join()`. Not even `console.log()` works inside `socket.join()`